# PHP code issue for whatsapp link generation

Tags: php

i wanted to concenate value so that whatsapp link can be generated. new to PHP so not able to do it. can any one help to fix below code.  `<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<?= '+' .$row['mobile']; ?>` this line causing error.

```php
$tempRow['whatsapp'] ="<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<?= '+' .$row['mobile']; ?>' target='_blank' title='Send Whatsapp Notification'> Send Whatsapp Notification</a>";
```

Comment: What error does it cause? Also, WhatsApp expects the number with international prefix but without the `+`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.